# Unable to setContentView with my tabhost with nested activities

Tags: android

My code below is based on this: http://web.archive.org/web/20100816175634/http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

My issue is with the history ArrayList that is supposed to store the activities so I can properly utilize the back button, however my app crashes when I hit back. I think it's because history isn't exactly storing Views.

I added:

```
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ViewPagerActivity", new
                                                Intent(this,ViewPagerActivity.class)
                                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                                                .getDecorView();
```

to my back method to see if it would load it and it works.

```
public class FeaturedTabGroup extends ActivityGroup {
         // Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nesten activities, lets them manipulate the view
            public static FeaturedTabGroup group;

        // Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.
            private ArrayList history;



        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.history = new ArrayList();
            group = this;


         // Start the root activity withing the group and get its view
              View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ViewPagerActivity", new
                                                Intent(this,ViewPagerActivity.class)
                                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                                                .getDecorView();

                // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
              replaceView(view);


        }


        public void replaceView(View v) {
            // Adds the old one to history
            history.add(v);
            // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
            setContentView(v);

            System.out.println("view set successful");
        }

        public void back() {

            if(history.size() > 0) {
                history.remove(history.size()-1);
                setContentView((Integer) history.get(history.size()-1));
            }else {
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            FeaturedTabGroup.group.back();
            return;
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

For brevity, I'll approach this problem with another question: why does setContentView(v) work, but not when the Views are store in an ArrayList? What happens to the view when it is stored in an arraylist?

Comment: FYI, you can get a full working example based on that Henrik Larsen Toft blog post over here: http://richipal.com/post/2624844577

Answer (score 0):

Can't you work around this issue with ViewSwitcher (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html)? It provides a cleaner solution and you could always call showPrevious() and showNext() when needed.

Comment: I dont think viewswitcher will work if I have more than two activities

Comment: You're right, using ViewSwitcher would mean that you would have to implement all the logic in a single activity, as well as the layouts in a single layout file. Although, it might be easier to navigate between your screens.

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(int) expects a layout resource ID. In your example, can you try to save the view object itself (i.e. without type cast to integer)? As jcXavier says - viewswitcher is a better way to handle this.

Comment: what does history.add(v); do? I thought it added the view object to the array?  Taking out the (Integer) gives me an error

Comment: Also, it is weird that the setContentView in replaceView method works. Arent both setContentViews getting the same activity views, with the back getting its view from an arrayList?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late , but here: `(history.size() > 0)`, change `0` to `1`, when size is 1, it should just finish.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

I know it must be late... but perhaps I can help somebody else.

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
public void back() {
    View v;
    if(history.size() > 1) {
        history.remove(history.size()-1);
        v = (View) history.get(history.size()-1);
        FirstGroup.group.setContentView(v);
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}
```